# Data validation and named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet generated through Access VBA. I populate ranges of cells from Access to use for Data Validation. The ranges are there and named, and this is checked by using the box in the top left of the spreadsheet.
When I try to validate I get the message "A named Range you specified cannot be found".  If I now use Ctrl F3 I can delete the range. Now I use exactly the same range and Type exactly the same Title into bow on top left and then everything works.  As far as I can see I am using exactly the same criteria throughout. Does anyone have any ideas ?

'Write "Constants" for =Indirect functions in Sheet(5)
            'Phone conversation with Paul.  These will now come from Tables
            '_______________________________________________________________

```
        Dim CL(1 To 6) As Integer ' This is to count "filled rows" when spreadsheet is filled
        Dim Header(1 To 6) As String
        Dim AddNameFormula As String

        Header(1) = "CostType"
        Header(2) = "SoftwareCosts"
        Header(3) = "HardwareCosts"
        Header(4) = "Expenses"
        Header(5) = "Travel"
        Header(6) = "Building"

        NRrows = RSNonResourceCosts.RecordCount ' Number of Rows in Non Resource Table
        NRcols = RSNonResourceCosts.Fields.Count ' Number of Fields in NonResource Table

        RSNonResourceCosts.MoveFirst

        For R = 1 To NRrows

        If (RSNonResourceCosts![CostType]) <> "" Then
        CL(1) = CL(1) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 1) = (RSNonResourceCosts![CostType])
        End If

        If (RSNonResourceCosts![SoftwareCosts]) <> "" Then
        CL(2) = CL(2) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 2) = (RSNonResourceCosts![SoftwareCosts])
        End If

        If (RSNonResourceCosts![HardwareCosts]) <> "" Then
        CL(3) = CL(3) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 3) = (RSNonResourceCosts![HardwareCosts])
        End If


        If (RSNonResourceCosts![Expenses]) <> "" Then
        CL(4) = CL(4) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 4) = (RSNonResourceCosts![Expenses])
        End If

        If (RSNonResourceCosts![Travel]) <> "" Then
        CL(5) = CL(5) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 5) = (RSNonResourceCosts![Travel])
        End If

        If (RSNonResourceCosts![Building]) <> "" Then
        CL(6) = CL(6) + 1
        WKS.Cells(199 + R, 6) = (RSNonResourceCosts![Building])
        End If

        RSNonResourceCosts.MoveNext

        Next R
```

1100
            '______________________________________________________
            Dim RCount As String
            Dim strRange As String
            Dim ColString As String

```
        For C = 1 To NRcols - 1
        X = CL(C) - 1

        X = X + 200
        RCount = Str(X)
        RCount = Right$(RCount, Len(RCount) - 1) '
        'strRange = "A201:A" + RCount
        strRange = Chr$(64 + C) & "200:" & Chr$(64 + C) & RCount



        MsgBox "strRange   " & strRange & "   Rcount  " & RCount

        WKS.Range(strRange).Select


        If C = 1 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)

        WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(1), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C1"
        End If

        If C = 2 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)
         WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(2), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C2"
        End If

        If C = 3 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)
         WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(3), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C3"
        End If

        If C = 4 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)
         WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(4), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C4"
        End If

        If C = 5 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)
        WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(5), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C5"
        End If

        If C = 6 Then
        ColString = Str(C)
        ColString = Right$(ColString, Len(ColString) - 1)
         WKS.Names.Add Name:=Header(6), RefersToR1C1:="=ProjectDetails!R200C" & ColString & ":R" & RCount & "C6"
        End If

        Next C

        I hope this might help.  Code is vast.
```

Comment: if you can post some screenshots of your data and named ranges formula, that may help us. Or even the Access VBA code may help, too.

Comment: How are these named ranges being created?  This feels like something to do with the "scope" of the named range.  If your named range is 1: Scoped to the worksheet and 2: On a different sheet than the data validation referencing it, you will get an error.